# How to insert an element in a very specific place using D3

Tags: dom, svg, d3.js

Say I have the following DOM structure:

```
div
  > svg
    > defs
    > g
      > rect
      > g
      > g
          <-- I want to insert an element here
      > g
      > g
```

None of the parent `g`'s child `g` elements have a class, id, or anything else I can use as a selector, and I cannot modify them because they are coming from a 3rd party widget loaded into the page.

The best I can do so far is insert into the 3rd `g` element, but that's not acceptable. I want to add a 6th element to the parent `g`'s children, between the current indices 2 and 3 (or indices 1 and 2 if you don't count the `rect`).

Here's what I have done so far:

```
var test = d3.selectAll('#continer svg > g > g');
test = d3.select(test[0][2]);
test.append('foreignObject').
    attr('width', 690).attr('height', 500)
    .append('xhtml:body').style('font', '14px "Helvetica Neue"')
    .html('<h1>An HTML Foreign Object in SVG</h1>');
```

With that I end up with the following structure:

```
div
  > svg
    > defs
    > g
      > rect
      > g
      > g
      > g
        > foreignobject & its children inserted here
      > g
```

... and I understand why. I have tried D3's `insert` method using a function as the second argument to specify `before`, but the browser keeps telling me:

> An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not
>   exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this works but it's a bit of a hack. I use jQuery to rearrange elements after appending using D3. Would still like to see a pure D3 solution to this if one is possible:

```
// select the parent g element
var parentG = d3.select('#continer svg > g');

// append a new G element with a nested foreign object
parentG.append('g').attr('id', '__my_custom_id')
    .append('foreignObject').attr('width', 690).attr('height', 500)
    .append('xhtml:body').style('font', '14px "Helvetica Neue"')
    .html('<h1>An HTML Foreign Object in SVG</h1>')
;

// now use jQuery to rearrange the order of the elements
$('#__my_custom_id')
    .insertAfter('#container svg > g > g:nth-child(3)')
    .removeAttr('id')
;
```